# Retrieve all values from a sub child in Firebase with Swift iOS

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, firebase, uicollectionview

I am trying to retrieve all the values from sub-child of Firebase to show in a label in the collection view.
I have to get connections outlets to a Collection View Cell and have a View controller having an image and three labels.
In the last label, I want to get all the price value from firebase child.

**Firebase Structure**

[image]

**ViewController**

[image]

**Retrieving values**

```
  import UIKit
  import  Firebase
 class CakeViewController:  UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate,   UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var manuCake: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var cakeCollectionView: UICollectionView!


struct cakeObject {

    var cakeImage : UIImage
    var cakeEnglichName: String
    var cakeUrduName : String
    var cakeRate : String
    var key : String



}

var cakeArray : [cakeObject] = []



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manuCake.target = revealViewController()
    manuCake.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())



    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {


            print(snapshot.value as Any)
            let cakeData = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
                for (key,value) in cakeData{
                    //Can set cakeImage and cakeUrduName as per your project
                    cakeArray.append(cakeObject(cakeImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bakery_almond_cake"),cakeEnglinhName: key, cakeUrduName: "آلمنڑ کیک", cakeRate: "\(value)/kg"))
                }
                self.cakeCollectionView.reloadData()
            }

    })



    cakeCollectionView.delegate = self
    cakeCollectionView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}





func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cakeArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CakeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        as! CakeCollectionViewCell

    cell.cakeImageView.image = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeImage
    cell.cakeEngLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeEnglichName
    cell.cakeUrLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeUrduName
    cell.cakeRateLabs.text =  cakeArray[indexPath.item].key

    return cell

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

**latest error**

[image]

**Another Way same class**

```
 import UIKit
 import  Firebase
 class CakeViewController:  UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate,   UICollectionViewDataSource {

@IBOutlet weak var manuCake: UIBarButtonItem!

@IBOutlet weak var cakeCollectionView: UICollectionView!


struct cakeObject {

    var cakeImage : UIImage
    var cakeEnglichName: String
    var cakeUrduName : String
    //var cakeRate : String
    var key : String



}

var cakeArray : [cakeObject] = []



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    manuCake.target = revealViewController()
    manuCake.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())



    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake").child("Almond_Cake")

    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        if snapshot.exists() {


            print(snapshot.value as Any)
             let cakeData = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
                for (key,value) in cakeData{
                    //Can set cakeImage and cakeUrduName as per your project
                    self.cakeArray.append(cakeObject(cakeImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bakery_almond_cake"),cakeEnglichName: key, cakeUrduName: "آلمنڑ کیک", key: "\(value)/kg"))
                }
                self.cakeCollectionView.reloadData()
            }
       })



    cakeCollectionView.delegate = self
    cakeCollectionView.dataSource = self

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}





func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return cakeArray.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CakeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
        as! CakeCollectionViewCell

    cell.cakeImageView.image = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeImage
    cell.cakeEngLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeEnglichName
    cell.cakeUrLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeUrduName
    cell.cakeRateLabs.text =  cakeArray[indexPath.item].key

    return cell

}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

}
```

**Another Ways Error**

[image]

Comment: Can you please add the console log for simply `snapshot.value` by adding `print(snapshot.value)`.

Comment: where should io do that?

Comment: After `if snapshot.exists() {` line add `print(snapshot.value)` and add the console log of it here.

Comment: updated questions with warings

Comment: i think `fruitArray[indexPath.item]["key"]`  should be `fruitArray[indexPath.item].key` For now comment other code and run app and then add the console log of print statement that I have asked.

Comment: builds fails i have updated the question with similar category as firebase child is but it fails to build

Comment: Would you please edit the code in question if possible. because i have updated the print( snapshot.value) but still builds fails.

Comment: For the first warning, you have to tell the compiler what looks like `snapshot.value`. Is it a Dict, is it an array ? Because, if it's doesn't know, how is it supposed to allow a `snapshot.value[someKey]`? So in your case, it's a Dictionary. Same for `fruitArray[i]`, how can it has a `"objectForKey:"key"`.

Comment: Actually i am new to firebase i am so confused. would you please edit and update the question? the new error is cakeviewcontroller.cakeObject has no member "key"

Comment: @Frank van Puffelen

Comment: For second error, `cakeArray` only contains `cakeObject` and `cakeObject` has no property named `key`. What do you want to display?

Comment: sorry i forgot to add

Comment: still errors can you please update the question? i want to retrieve all the vales of Cake child to an array in label in a collections view cell

Comment: @NiravD please help to accomplish this

Comment: @Xcoder123 please help to accomplish this

Comment: @GeneCode please help to accomplish this

Answer (score 2):

you are getting below error as the value is not array of dictionary, value there is string.

```
if let cake = snapshot.value![a] as? [[String:String]]
```

it should be

```
if let cake = snapshot.value![a] as? String
```

Don't see use of **fruitArray** after assign cake rate in **fruitArray**

I would suggest you to fill cakeArray as below code:

```
print(snapshot.value as Any)
let cakeData = snapshot.value as! [String:String]
    for (key,value) in cakeData{
           //Can set cakeImage and cakeUrduName as per your project
           cakeArray.append(cakeObject(cakeImage: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "bakery_almond_cake"),cakeEnglinhName: key, cakeUrduName: "آلمنڑ کیک", cakeRate: "\(value)/kg"))                  
      }
    self.cakeCollectionView.reloadData()
```

**Second error**: I don't see any object as key in cake struct. So compiler is give error. You are assigning value in previous line for `cakeRateLabs`. So no need to assign again just remove/comment `cell.cakeRateLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].key`.

Hope This will surely solve your error and get output as your want.

Comment: Thankyou so much for your kind response but i am getting an error --- use of unresolved identifier 'a' --- i have updated picture of error in question as well as updated the question with latest code

Comment: write 'key' not 'a' my mistake I replace 'a' with 'key'. but forget at one place. make it 'snapshot.value![key]'

Comment: Thanks dear but still there is erro in [key] 'type 'any' has no subscript members' updated error picture and code

Comment: take snapshot value in dictionary then do further operations. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support but still got error, updated code and error picture please get a look and help me to accomplish this.

Comment: make as? instead of as!

Comment: Sir awaiting for your kind response please help me to accomplish this.

Comment: remove if statement compiler is telling that no need to use if statement. Updated my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137056/discussion-between-sschunara-and-xcodian).

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a new class and new fetch func. See how this works for you,

```
class CakeData {
   var cakeImage : UIImage?
   var cakeEnglichName: String?
   var cakeUrduName : String?
   //var cakeRate : String
    var key : String?
 init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary <String, Any>) {
       self.key = postKey

       //Don't forget to add your keys
       if let cakeImage   = postData["addKey"] {
          self.cakeImage = cakeImage as? UIImage
       }
       if let cakeEnglichName = postData["addKey"] {
          self.cakeEnglichName = cakeEnglichName as? String
       }
       if let cakeUrduName = postData["addKey"] {
          self.cakeUrduName = cakeUrduName as? String
       }
     }
```

Fetch Function,

```
func fetchCakeData() {
    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
ref.child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
       if let cakeSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
           for cakes in cakeSnapshot {
               if let cakeDictionary = cakes.value as? Dictionary <String, Any> {
                   let key = cakes.key as String
                   //your class that takes a key as String and a Dictionary
                   let post = CakeData(postKey:key, postData: cakeDictionary)
                   self.cakeArray.append(post)
               }
           }
       }
      cakeCollectionView.delegate = self
     cakeCollectionView.dataSource = self
   })
}
```

here it is according to your code,

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

struct cakeObject {
    var cakeImage : UIImage
    var cakeEnglichName: String
    var cakeUrduName : String
    // var cakeRate : String
    var key : String
}
class CakeData {
    var cakeImage : UIImage?
    var cakeEnglichName: String?
    var cakeUrduName : String?
    //var cakeRate : String
    var key : String?
    init(postKey: String, postData: Dictionary <String, Any>) {
        self.key = postKey

        //Don't forget to add your keys
        if let cakeImage   = postData["addKey"] {
            self.cakeImage = cakeImage as? UIImage
        }
        if let cakeEnglichName = postData["addKey"] {
            self.cakeEnglichName = cakeEnglichName as? String
        }
        if let cakeUrduName = postData["addKey"] {
            self.cakeUrduName = cakeUrduName as? String
        }
    }
}


class CakeViewController: UIViewController , UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var manuCake: UIBarButtonItem!
    @IBOutlet weak var cakeCollectionView: UICollectionView!
    var cakeArray: [CakeData] = []
// var cakeArray : [cakeObject] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        manuCake.target = revealViewController()
        manuCake.action = #selector(SWRevealViewController.revealToggle(_:))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(self.revealViewController().panGestureRecognizer())
        self.cakeCollectionView.delegate = self
        self.cakeCollectionView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        fetchCakeData()
    }

    func fetchCakeData() {
        let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
        ref.child("Hyderabad").child("Bakery").child("Cake").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in
            if let cakeSnapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
                for cakes in cakeSnapshot {
                    if let cakeDictionary = cakes.value as? Dictionary <String, Any> {
                        let key = cakes.key as String
                        //your class that takes a key as String and a Dictionary
                        let post = CakeData(postKey:key, postData: cakeDictionary)
                        self.cakeArray.append(post)
                    }
                }
            }
            self.cakeCollectionView.reloadData()
        })
    }




 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return cakeArray.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CakeCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath)
            as! CakeCollectionViewCell

        cell.cakeImageView.image = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeImage
        cell.cakeEngLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeEnglichName
        cell.cakeUrLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeUrduName
        cell.cakeRateLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].key



        print("Cake : \(cakeArray[indexPath.row])")
        cell.cakeImageView.image = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeImage
        cell.cakeEngLabs.text = cakeArray[indexPath.item].cakeEnglichName


        return cell 
    }


}
```

Comment: found error in 'post' : can not covert the value of type CakeData to expected argument type cakeviewcontroller.cakeObject

Comment: would you like to post complete class and how it is arranged

Comment: I do not quite understand how you are calling it but make sure that the cakeArray is of type CakeData [CakeData].

Comment: please post complete class i have issue in re-arrangement

Comment: This is everything I wrote. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: i am getting error at 'self.cakeArray.append(post)'    cannot convert the value of type 'CakeData' to expected argument type 'CakeViewController.cakeObject'

Comment: is your property like this 'var cakeArray: [CakeData] = []

Comment: Build successful but view controller does not show anything

Comment: reload your collectionView, take these / cakeCollectionView.delegate = self
     cakeCollectionView.dataSource = self and put them in your viewDidLoad and then cakeCollectionView.reloadData where you set your delegates.

Comment: please refine complete class and find the issue thanks advance

Comment: i think we did not wrote the values to print? am i eright?

Comment: Move you func out of the viewDidLoad. Add the delegates in the viewDidLoad. Take the delegates from the func. Add yourcollectionView.reloadData() in your func where you set the delegates, call the func in viewWillAppear add the CakeData class I created for you to your project.

Comment: would you please arrange the entire class please just edit your answer please

Comment: I am about to post it.

Comment: you need to add yourKeys. I typed addKey where you need a key. I didn't add them cause I do not know what they are.

Comment: invalid declaration of CakeData

Comment: You are running two of the same class I put the CakeData class in your vc, you must have it in another swift file.

Comment: so what should i do that sir, please guide me

Comment: look at my comment above.

Comment: yes still error in 'CakeData' is ambigous for type  lookup in this context